# Why is my slack Slash command app on Lambda invoking every 4 minutes?

Tags: python, lambda, zappa, slack-commands

I created a slash command for Slack and using Lambda as a serverless method. I followed a couple of tutorials online, built the app locally with Python and flask and then uploaded it with Zappa. The slash command works great but when I take a look at the lambda logs, it shows the function is being invoked every 4 minutes? - I'm obviously getting charged for this and I want it to only invoke when being called.

Can anyone shed some light on this - new to Lambda.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These invocations probably are related to cold start prevention, take a look on this [article](https://www.serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm/).

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for that article! - So my function pretty much stays warm so when I call it, it'll send a quick response - which is great. But this probably means I am getting charged more to keep it warm?
if that's the case then I would rather keep it cold...online it only shows how to keep a lambda function warm.

Comment: Take a look on this [doc](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#advanced-usage)